Deleting Google Calendar event not triggering RSVP email
I'm sending a meeting invite through an .ics file attachment in an email. Clicking "yes" or "no" or proposing a new time in the Google Calendar UI triggers an RSVP email to the email specified in the "organizer" field of the .ics file.
However, when clicking the trash icon in Google calendar and deleting the event, an RSVP email is not triggered. When manually creating an event through Google Calendar with guests, deleting the event does trigger an rsvp email.
How come it works when creating the event directly through Google Calendar, but not when sending a meeting invitation through the .ics file?. Could it have something to do with the format of the ics file?
Here is the contents of the .ics file I'm attaching to the invite email:
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
PRODID:adamgibbons/ics
METHOD:REQUEST
X-PUBLISHED-TTL:PT1H
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:7f6c6929-92d6-4c99-a609-5b042abdbdfb
SUMMARY:Meeting | John Doe
DTSTAMP:20240524T120000Z
DTSTART:20240605T070000Z
DTEND:20240605T075000Z
SEQUENCE:0
DESCRIPTION:Some description
LOCATION:Online | Name of our platform
STATUS:CONFIRMED
ORGANIZER;CN=Platform:mailto:mail@parse.platformname.com
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
CLASS:PRIVATE
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;CN=John Doe:mail
    to:johndoe@example.com
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;CN=Other person
    :mailto:otherperson@example.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

I was expecting the deletion of the calendar event in Google Calendar to trigger an RSVP email to the event organizer. Instead, nothing happens (the event disappears from the person who deleted the event's calendar)

It seems like sending RSVP emails upon event deletion only happens for events that are created through Google Calendar. I tested this by inviting a Google user to an event created through Microsoft Outlook. When deleting the event in Google Calendar, the outlook user didn't get an RSVP email.
So the functionality I was looking for is not possible

If anyone knows of information that might suggest otherwise, please let me know, and I'll be sure to update the correct answer
